# Active Content enable issue for WP8 using Phonegap & JQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-plugins

I am develpoing a Windows Phone 8 application using phonegap and jquery mobile. When I run my app on emulator, UI got disturbed.

When I run my `index.html` file on internal web browser then i get this message:

> Your web browser has restricted this file from showing active content
>   that could access your computer.

I think jQuery mobile script has been restricted by web browser.

Is this disabled by java script code?

Comment: ... more information please. Internet Explorer Version etc.